# Start profiling button is not starting recording in Flipper React DevTools (4.24.3) for React Native?

Tags: react-native, profiling, react-devtools, flipper, flamegraph

I'm trying to create a Flame Graph for my app.

I can't seem to start the Performance Recording though, as on clicking start profiling button recording is not starting:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzJpe.jpg

## To Reproduce

- Open app
- Open Flipper
- Connect to App (select it in dropdown)
- Switch to React DevTools
- Open Profiler Tab
- Click "Record" or "Start Profiling" button (circle)

## Environment

"react-native-flipper": "^0.176.1",
"react-native": "0.67.4",
Flipper Desktop app: 0.176.1

Didn't started recording and no flipper logs were there

Comment: having the same issue. Will update when I find a fix.

Comment: found the fix @rajat-bothra

Answer (score 2):

Was dealing with the same issue and it was driving me nuts. I believe this is the fix that got it working, then in flipper select use globally installed DevTools:

```
npm install -g react-devtools react-devtools-inline
```

[image: globally installed DevTools]: